# Django upload multiple files many to many

Tags: django, many-to-many

I want to know, is it my code ok?

What i want: create form with feature uploading multiple files. 
Can someone say about many-to-many? Is it ok?

I want to upload many files. How it can be?

---

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import uuid
from django.db import models

def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return os.path.join('file_uploads/%Y/%m', filename)

# Create your models here.
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

Updated: I get error when i'm trying to makemigrations command:

```
File "/home/dima/web/files_2016_04/fileupl/flpp/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Order(models.Model):
  File "/home/dima/web/files_2016_04/fileupl/flpp/models.py", line 16, in Order
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
NameError: name 'File' is not defined
```

But it defined. Whats wrong?
Updated: i solve this problem moving File class before Order class

**UPD** Thanks, i solved problem with ForeignKey('File') with quotes

Comment: If youn want that Orders may share files, then its ok. I would go for a ForeignKey on File to Order.

Comment: i want feature uploading multiple files in form for users/people

Comment: you saying foreignkey and this means that model will support only single file? But i want multiple

Comment: If you add an ForeignKey to your File model which points to your Order model you can have as many files as you want attached to one Order.

Comment: realy? i don't beleive it... but wait a minute, it is a true actualy, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare File class upper than Order class

```
# Create your models here.
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the current structure, you'll need to put it in quotes:

files = models.ManyToManyField('File')

Comment: So you mean that i can reorder and i will not get these errors if i use string in the paranthesis?

Comment: Exactly. The File class does not exist when you try to add it as a ManyToManyField.